# Is there a JS design pattern to combine N objects into 1 façade object and have code editors know which methods it has?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, design-patterns

for example suppose I have:

```
var obj_a = {
  foo: function() {}
}

var obj_b = {
  bar: function() {}
}
```

How should I declare `obj_c` to have both methods so that typing `obj_c.` would popup `foo` and `bar` as valid autocomplete options?

Comment: `Object.assign`

Answer (score 2):

I understand that you are looking for an **IntelliSense** equivalent, but if you need to create an `obj_c` which contains the properties of `obj_a` and `obj_b`, you can do so programmatically by using `Object.assign`:

```
const obj_c = Object.assign(obj_a, obj_b);
```

---

**Working Example:**

```js
const obj_a = {
  foo: function() {}
}

const obj_b = {
  bar: function() {}
}

const obj_c = Object.assign({}, obj_a, obj_b)

console.log(obj_c);
```

Comment: This mutates `obj_a`. If that is not desirable, `Object.assign({}, obj_a, obj_b)` can be used.

Comment: Good catch, @Unmitigated. Thanks for that correction. Updated.